# cocos2d, CC_HONOR_PARENT_TRANSFORM_SCALE, how do i use this enum property?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I want to add a sprite2 to sprite1, scale the width of of sprite 1 without scaling sprite2.

I found the code below part of the Cocos2d api; CCSprite.h line 54, but I don't know how to use it nor what the "1<<2" means.

Basically, I'm doing the following but it's not working:

[self addChild: sprite1];

[sprite1 addChild: sprite2]

sprite1.scaleX = 2;

sprite2.CC_HONOR_PARENT_TRANSFORM_SCALE = false;???

Yeah not sure how to use the enum.

thank you

```
typedef enum {
//! Translate with it's parent
CC_HONOR_PARENT_TRANSFORM_TRANSLATE =  1 << 0,
//! Rotate with it's parent
CC_HONOR_PARENT_TRANSFORM_ROTATE    =  1 << 1,
//! Scale with it's parent
CC_HONOR_PARENT_TRANSFORM_SCALE     =  1 << 2,

//! All possible transformation enabled. Default value.
CC_HONOR_PARENT_TRANSFORM_ALL       =  CC_HONOR_PARENT_TRANSFORM_TRANSLATE | CC_HONOR_PARENT_TRANSFORM_ROTATE | CC_HONOR_PARENT_TRANSFORM_SCALE,
```

} ccHonorParentTransform;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<<  - is a bit operation of a shift (my native language is russian and i've translated as is - not sure it's correct). But it is not required for you to understand how it work in this situation because in this case it's just a method to fill the enum values.

From cocos2d documentation

`- (ccHonorParentTransform) honorParentTransform [read, write, assign]`
whether or not to transform according to its parent transfomrations. Useful for health bars. eg: Don't rotate the health bar, even if the parent rotates. **IMPORTANT**: Only valid if it is rendered using an CCSpriteBatchNode.

Are you using batch rendering ?

**EDIT:**

This line is very strange (doesn't it give a warning?)

```
 sprite2.CC_HONOR_PARENT_TRANSFORM_SCALE = false
```

You should write

```
sprite2.honorParentTransform &= ~CC_HONOR_PARENT_TRANSFORM_SCALE;
```

**PS:** The enum is created using bit operations because it's give you the ability to misc the configuration. For example you can write

```
sprite2.honorParentTransform &= ~(CC_HONOR_PARENT_TRANSFORM_SCALE | CC_HONOR_PARENT_TRANSFORM_ROTATE);
```

It will enable both translate and rotate
So the honorParentTransform is a bitmask, that allows you to configure it's configuration - not only use some predefined values but also use there combinations.

Here you can write more about bitwise operations
http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html

In our case is happening something like this:
You have a current mask for example `01101111` (it is 32 bit really)
and CC_HONOR_PARENT_TRANSFORM_SCALE is something like this `00001000` - it have only one nonzero bit. `~` - is inversion: so it transform `00010000` to `11101111` and then you make the bitwise addition with you current mask - so all the bits will be preserved except the forth one!

Comment: yes, i'm using ccSpriteBatchNode, but how am i supposed to use honorParentTransform?

Comment: Do i set the value of honorParentTransfor property to true, false, 0 , 1 , 2 , 3, 4???